# Sum of digits of Fibonacci number a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

During my problem solving with Fibonacci numbers  following thought crossed my mind.

> How many Fibonacci numbers are there such that sum of its digits is a perfect square?

Here is a list of Fibonacci numbers: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, and I observe that only 13 and 144 are satisfying the condition. Is there any other? How to analyze the situation?

Comment: Did you forget 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sequence [A065411](https://oeis.org/A065411), the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences has tabulated more Fibonacci numbers with this property. The next few are $806515533049393$, $61305790721611591$, $83621143489848422977$. There is probably not a good way to find these numbers other than just computing the sequence of Fibonacci numbers and testing whether the sum of digits is a square.

Comment: Where are these in the sequence? Like, if $F_n$ equals the first number you've listed there, what's $n$?

Comment: Never mind: They're the 73rd, 82nd, and 97th Fibonacci numbers.